# Cloud Function split a string into words

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase collection that is full of data, and in that data i have a column called fullname.

Ive created another column called `customname`, and here i would like to copy the `fullname` but split it into words and re enter it in another format to `customname`

for example : `Jamie Warren` would become `Warren, Jamie`

I tried the following, but nothing seemed to happen when running the function, also i realised if a name is for example Jamie John Brian Warren, what's the best way to put it as `Warren, Jamie John Brian`

```
const extensionBody: TaskBody = async({row, db, change, ref, logging}) => {
var fullname =  row.fullName.split(" ");
var newname = fullname[0] + "," + fullname[1];
  ref.update({
  customName: fullname
  
  })
}
```

I am really new to this cloud function stuff, so thought i could get some advice here.

Tried the code above, but nothing resulted.

Answer (score 2):

Your function correct claims that its `async`, but then fails to return a promise - or use `await` in its body to handle the asynchronous operation. That means that Cloud Functions can terminate the runtime at any moment after it encounters the final `}`, which is typically well before the `update` of the database has completed.

To fix the problem `return` or `await` the promise returned by `update`. So:

```
return ref.update({
  customName: fullname
})
```

Or:

```
await ref.update({
  customName: fullname
})
```